# Initialize const char* by concatenating another char*

Tags: c++, initialization, concatenation, const-char

I want to refactor:

```
const char* arr = 
  "The "
  "quick "
  "brown";
```

into something like:

```
const char* quick = "quick ";
const char* arr = 
  "The "
  quick
  "brown";
```

because the string "quick" is used is many other places. Ideally I need to be able to do this with just const primitive types, so no string. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Rarely the case is so, but a preprocessor macro would seem more appropriate.

Comment: You can't reuse sub-strings. Each literal string has to be consecutive in memory. If you want to optimize memory usage, then you have to do it by code (i.e., during runtime).

Comment: Or use std::string and concatenate them. I don't know if that has performance implications for you.

Comment: No performance issues but this is a global variable inside an anonymous namespace and it's company policy to have only primitive types outside classes/functions due to indeterminate initialization order. And I  like to avoid macros when I can (eg here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling the comments in the form of an answer:

1. Use a macro.

   ```
   #define QUICK "quick "

   char const* arr = "The " QUICK "brown";
   ```
2. Use `std:string`.

   ```
   std::string quick = "quick ";
   std::string arr = std::string("The ") + quick + "brown";
   ```

Working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define QUICK "quick "

void test1()
{
   char const* arr = "The " QUICK "brown";
   std::cout << arr << std::endl;
}

void test2()
{
   std::string quick = "quick ";
   std::string arr = std::string("The ") + quick + "brown";
   std::cout << arr << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   test1();
   test2();
}
```

Output:

```
The quick brown
The quick brown
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. I think I'll use string and hide it inside another function. I wish I can upvote everyone who contributed rather than the aggregator, but hey! that's how life works too.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that what I want to do can't be done, that was definitely very helpful.