# best way to add char* prefix to existing char* in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

What I have:

```
char * a = "world";
char * b = "Hello";
```

What I need is:

```
char * a = "Hello World";
```

I need to add b before a.
Is there any function that doing it?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a new string.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807775/initialize-const-char-by-concatenating-another-char/26808009#26808009

Answer (score 3):

You could use [strcat(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html), [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)

With `strcat` you need to check against [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (using [strlen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html)...)
With `strcat` & `snprintf`, you need to pre-allocate the array.
With `asprintf` you are given a heap-allocated buffer as a result, and you'll need to `free` it appropriately.

So, using `strcat` and a fixed-size buffer `buf`:

```
char buf[64];
if (strlen(a)+strlen(b)<sizeof(buf)) {
  strcpy(buf, a);
  strcat(buf, b);
}
// now buf contains "worldhello"
```

Alternatively you might use a heap-allocated buffer:
 `char*buf = malloc(strlen(a)+strlen(b)+1);` but don't forget to check against `malloc` failure: `if (!buf) { perror("malloc buf"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };` and then do the `strcpy` & `strcat` as before. Of course you'll need to `free(buf)` later at the appropriate time. Notice that you could keep `int lena=strlen(a);` then `strcpy(buf+lena,b)` instead of calling `strcat`.

Using `snprintf` and a fixed-size buffer `buf` (no need to check against buffer overflow since `snprintf` is given the buffer size):

```
char buf[54];
int len= snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%s", a, b);
// now buf contains "worldhello" and len contains the required length
```

The nice thing about `snprintf` is that is understands `printf` format control strings (e.g. `%d` for integer in decimal, `%g` for floating point in scientific notation, etc...)

Using `asprintf` (on systems like Linux which provide it)

```
char* buf = asprintf("%s%s", a, b);
```

But you need to call `free(buf)` at the appropriate moment to avoid a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

See also [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html), [fmemopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) and `open_memstream`

<sup>In your question you should swap `a` and `b`</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It can be done easily as shown below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{
char * a = "world";
char * b = "Hello";
char *c = malloc(strlen(a)+strlen(b)+1);
strcpy(c,b);
strcat(c,a);
printf("%s\n",c);
free(c);
}
```

Comment: Couple of suggestion to add to this answer: take strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1 as the size instead of hard coding it to 20, and remember to check for malloc failures to avoid GPF/Segfault.

Comment: @Chris Just showed how it can be done but agree with you hardcoding is never a good idea

Comment: completely understood, not inferring in anyway anything negative :) I like to take advantage in these types of questions to expose such considerations to new developers if I can. Good skills for the future and all that. Cheers.