# How to append a user inputted char* to the initialization of a const char*

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a connection to a postgres database from C++ and ask for the password from the user. 
Here is the code in question:

```
    char* pass;
    cout << "Please enter password for user: Mickey" << endl;
    cin >> pass;

    const char *connectInfo = "host=cs-linux dbname=gbianchet user=mickey password=" + pass;
```

I am wondering how I can get the user's input and append it to the end of the the initialization for connectInfo.

I have searched for the answer to this question and have found these links, [Initialize const char* by concatenating another char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807775/initialize-const-char-by-concatenating-another-char) and [How to cleanly use: const char* and std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941456/how-to-cleanly-use-const-char-and-stdstring), but they don't quite answer my question.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references you gave in your question are actually not appending or concatenating in `const char *` they used [Preprocessor Directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

This is the easy and proper way to achieve the same thing

```
string pass;
cout << "Please enter password for user: Mickey" << endl;
getline(cin, pass);
string connectionString("host=cs-linux dbname=gbianchet user=mickey password=" + pass);
const char *connectInfo = connectionString.c_str();
```

include string class header in your source code as `#include <string>`
**string** class is in `std` namespace

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Create your desired string using c++ string and then call the method .c_str() (see the above link)

For a given c++ string, it'll return you a NULL terminated c-string version of the c++ string that you can pass to your function that expects a c-string.